# Xamarin project of visual studio 2015 not found emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

In Xamarin.Form (portable) project , I can't found any android emulator,
but Xamarin.Form (shared) project can use android emulator .

Dev Too : Visual studio 2015 update 2

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: you should double check your installment to see if the emulators really are installed as well. Some emulators are provided by VS Setup, some by xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a Project as start projekt, if you want to build the IOS App it musst be your ios project and for android it must be the android project otherwise ther will be no emulator showen.

Comment: Hi , i want to run test for android :) , not iOS

Comment: do you have selected android as start project and also created some android devices in your emulator ?

Comment: Hi , yes , I selected android as start project and also created some android devices in emulator . I reinstall xamarin , the problem fixed , thanks for your help :).